# Is there a way to override cursor behavior through winapi in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I'd like to change the cursor image while my excel macro is running. I managed to change the cursor through these winapi functions : [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor) and [LoadCursorFromFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorfromfilea).

Here is an example :

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function LoadCursorFromFileA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
Declare Function SetCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal hCursor As Long) As Long

Sub TestCursor()
     Call SetCursor(LoadCursorFromFileA("C:\Temp\cursor2.cur"))
    ' Waits 5 seconds, any movement of the mouse will revert the cursor back to default
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    ' Cursor is back to default at the end of the sub
End Sub
```

However the cursor will change back to default if there is an event (like a dialog window) or if the cursor is moved.

It seems from [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428737-custom-cursor.html) that Excel updates the cursor when hovering over elements.

I found a [solution](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/428737-custom-cursor.html#post2120374) but it's preventing my macro to run because it's using an infinite loop.

Is there a way to override how Excel interacts with the cursor ?

Comment: What are you trying to do *exactly*? Seems to me hijacking WM messages to take full control of the mouse pointer is waaaaay overkill. LOTS of things beyond your control will send WM messages into the message loop to change the cursor's appearance. The infinite loop is *somewhat* sensible, since the alternative involves subclassing (i.e. entering the Windows Messenging loop yourself)... not something you'd typically do in everyday VBA code. "While my macro is running" isn't very clear.. are you trying to change the cursor to a hourglass? See `Application.Cursor` then. Otherwise... good luck!

Comment: In the simplest way I can put it : I'd like to use a custom image to replace the cursor while my macro is working (calculations and formatting mostly).
I managed to change the cursor to a custom image but there is some updating in Excel putting it back to the default cursor.
I know about `Application.Cursor` but it doesn't provide support for custom images.

I know it will probably be way overkill but at this point it's just out of curiosity and learning some more complex way to use VBA.

Comment: Hmm. That's one battle I'd choose not to fight (subclassing is rather flaky in VBA), and just go with `Application.Cursor = xlWait` while macro is running. If you only need the cursor for a `UserForm`, consider tweaking the `MousePointer` property as suggested under "using a custom mouse pointer" in [this article](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/change-mouse-cursor-icon-in-vba-userform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some sample subclassing code. In Excel `Application.hWnd` has the hWnd you want.

```
Public Const WM_SETCURSOR = &H20
```

When you get above message return True (-1) to stop further changes in cursor.

```
gWindowProc = true
```

---

```
Public Sub Hook()
   lpPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(EditNote.gRtfHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, _
   AddressOf gWindowProc)
End Sub

Public Sub Unhook()
   Dim temp As Long
   temp = SetWindowLong(EditNote.gRtfHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, lpPrevWndProc)
End Sub

Public Function gWindowProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, _
                 ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
   If Msg = WM_CONTEXTMENU Then
        If EditNote.mnuViewEditContextMenu.Checked Then EditNote.PopupMenu EditNote.mnuEdit
'        gWindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, _
         lParam)
   Else ' Send all other messages to the default message handler
      gWindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hwnd, Msg, wParam, _
         lParam)
   End If
End Function
```

> Remarks
>
> The high-order word of lParam is zero when the window enters menu mode. 
>   The DefWindowProc function passes the WM_SETCURSOR message to a parent
>   window before processing. If the parent window returns TRUE, further
>   processing is halted. Passing the message to a window's parent window
>   gives the parent window control over the cursor's setting in a child
>   window. The DefWindowProc function also uses this message to set the
>   cursor to an arrow if it is not in the client area, or to the
>   registered class cursor if it is in the client area. If the low-order
>   word of the lParam parameter is HTERROR and the high-order word of
>   lParam specifies that one of the mouse buttons is pressed,
>   DefWindowProc calls the MessageBeep function.

MSDN 2001

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and almost working. It works great if my cursor is over the ribbon but if the cursor is over a window (the internal windows of Excel) the cursor will revert back to default. Looks like the windows send their own message and I can't intercept it using the Application handle. I tried to use the window handle but I get `error 438 : object doesn't support this property or method`.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#examining-a-message-queue about `PeekMessage()`. Or Create a 100 ms timer that sets the cursor.